# Initializers and copy

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I've just been reading a short blog post from [Craig Hockenberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132867/chockenberry) about [**ARC and copy**](http://furbo.org/2012/05/04/arc-and-copy/). The question I now have is should parameters passed to initializers that are assigned to instance variables always use `copy`? Or does it depend on the type of the instance variable?

```
#import "MyObject.h"

@implementation MyObject {
    SomeType *_ivar1;
    SomeOtherType *_ivar2;
}

-(id)initWithParam1:(SomeType *)param1 andParam2:(SomeOtherType *)param2
{
    if ((self == [super init])) {
        _ivar1 = [param1 copy]; // Always good
        _ivar2 = [param2 copy]; // practice?
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: It looks to me like Craig is only warning about setting the backing ivar for a property that's got a `copy` specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of the variable and intent.

For simple types -- NSString, NSArray, NSNumber, etc... -- you use copy because you generally want the stored type to be immutable.   I.e. it doesn't make sense to have a `firstName` property where something externally can modify it by passing in an instance of `NSMutableString`.

For more complex classes -- ones that encapsulate both state and functionality -- you generally do not want to copy it exactly because that state may be changing over time. For example, if your app were a streaming video app that had a VideoPlayer instance that played a video encapsulated in a StreamingVideo instance, you wouldn't want to copy the StreamingVideo as its internal state is constantly going to be changing as more data is downloaded (or an error occurs).

I.e. `copy` is used when you want an immutable snapshot of state and a reference is used when you want object A to be connected to B for purposes of changing/monitoring/querying B's state.

And, yes, you want it to be consistent.  If a property is `copy` and you have a convenience initializer that sets that property, make sure the convenience initializer also copies whatever is set to the property.

Comment: My general rule: if the type being stored has a mutable subclass, you should be using copy (for both the property and in init).

Answer (score 4):

I think the key to understanding the post is in this statement:

> Since I think it’s a bad idea to use accessors during -init the copy semantics defined by the `@property` are never used and ARC happily retains the reference instead of copying it.

I think that Craig is talking specifically about the following case:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    SomeType *_ivar1;
}
-(id)initWithParam1:(SomeType *)param1;
@property (copy, nonatomic) SomeType* prop1;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize prop1 = _ivar1;
-(id)initWithParam1:(SomeType *)param1 {
    if ((self == [super init])) {
        /*
        Craig could have called

        self.prop1 = param1;

        but he believes that it's a bad idea to call accessors
        from the initializer, so he calls copy explicitly.
        */
        _ivar1 = [param1 copy];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: @JohnTopley would you mind explaining your reason for the downvote?

Comment: @dasblikenlight You gave a fine answer, but it wasn't to the question I actually asked! Having said that, I think a downvote was probably a bit harsh, but unfortunately my vote is now locked unless you edit your answer.